# R profile, setting prompt to the date

Tags: r

I'm going through Chamber's "Programming With Data: A Guide to the S Language", and I'm trying to get my prompt to display the data. For example, instead of "R> ", I would have "Nov 17: ".

I have created an .Rprofile and added the following:

```
options(prompt=system("date '+%b %e: '"))
```

However, when I run an R session I get this:

```
Nov 17: 
0
0
0
```

Is there a way to get this to work?
Thanks

Edit 1: My version of R is 3.0.0 and I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple:

```
options(prompt=paste(Sys.Date(),"> "))
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the solution by Thomas, but formatted like you want

```
> options(prompt=strftime(Sys.Date(),"%b %e: "))
Nov 17:
```